# Edit and save shared preferences in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can access shared preferences in Android Studio from Device file explorer, but after editing the file, the changed values aren't saved. How can I save the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can access shared preferences in Android Studio from Device file explorer, but after editing the file, the changed values aren't saved. How can I save the changes?

You're not editing the files directly. When you open a file that's on the device, Android Studio is actually pulling a copy to your local machine.

For example, if I selected this random `i_log` file from my SDCard it ends up here on my local machine under `Documents` on Mac (shown in the top status bar in Android Studio).
[image]

If you want to save the changes back to the device, you need to "upload" the file back to the device.

1. On the folder in the device explorer you want to move the file to, right-click.
2. Select **Upload..**

[image]

3. In the file chooser dialog, navigate to the local copy you edited.

[image]

AS will push that file back to the device.

Comment: my android smart phone is rooted and  connected through USB to PC, but after editing shared preferences and sync, if close and reopen shared preferences file, nothing is changed

Comment: Post the code of how you save your preferences.

Comment: im trying to edit sharedpreferences.xml through  android studio **file explorer** , it contains some `<string name="test"> testValue</string>` tag

Comment: @thanks for editing. is it possible to select the local copy file that is opened in android studio , or i should first save it on a location , then select it ?

Comment: Yes, you already have a local copy on your machine that AS downloaded when you opened the file. Just edit and select that same file. Added this to my answer.

Comment: When using the same file multiple times it is useful to add the folder to favourites in Finder / File Explorer. Saves you a lot of clicks.

Answer (score 1):

to access to shared preferences file that's identified by the resource string use the following code:

**Kotlin:**

```
var sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

**Java:**

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

it using the private mode so the file is accessible by only your app.

you can use the following code to write to sharedpref:

**Kotlin:**

```
   val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
   with (sharedPref.edit()) {
       putInt("number", num)
       apply()
   }
```

**Java:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("number", num);
editor.apply();
```

you can put boolean,string and etc to your sharedpref file.

then if you want to get that value you can say:

```
   val num = sharedPref.getInt("number", defvalue = 0 )
```

as you know you can getBoolean, getString and etc

Refer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) as well.

Comment: thanks @Hassan , but the question is about how to edit shared preferences through device file explorer or something similar, not coding java or kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use a tool like Facebook's [flipper](https://fbflipper.com) which, amongst other things, allows you to [edit SharedPreferences live](https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/plugins/preferences/).

Note, you need to integrate it with your app. It's fairly straightforward though and can be done in such a manner, that release versions are not affected by it at all.